# Converting PDF layout using a tool

Tags: pdf, page-layout, layout

I have a rather large single-page layout PDF which needs to be converted into spreads (it's too large to do this manually in a reasonable amount of time).  What software could I used for this?  I imagine there must be software for doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: [Preps](https://workflowhelp.kodak.com/display/PREPS82/KODAK+PREPS+Imposition+Software+8.2) is traditionally software used to impose PDFs. But it's *not* cheap by any means. Manual *may be* your best bet if cost is a concern. Easy enough to do with InDesign.... and I imagine QuarkXPress as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been recommended to use PitStop Server Pro

Comment: Hello user1409059, welcome to GDSE. While this is probably an honest attempt at helping, it would be better if you didn't just include the name of the software, but also _why_ you think it would be suited for the questioners needs. You can [edit] your answer. Thanks!